# Is there a way to get more detailed logging out of Forefront TMG 2010

Tags: microsoft-forefront-2010

I am troubleshooting VPN connectivity issues with Forefront TMG. Everything looks correct in configuration but the packets are blocked regardless.

The logs are not very descriptive. I see:

```
Denied Connection
Log type: Firewall service 
Status: The policy rules do not allow the user request.  
Rule: Default rule 
Source:
Destination:
Protocol
```

Is there a way to obtain a more detailed log within the TMG Management console? Note: using Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is using Diagnostic Logging:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897091.aspx